# How can I create a hybrid strategy in Devise that is valid only when one of its "parent" strategies are valid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm working on a hybrid strategy between `ldap_authenticatable` ([link](https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable)) and `database_authenticatable` ([link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/strategies/database_authenticatable.rb)).

I have it all working with the exception of the `Devise::Strategies::LdapAndDatabaseAuthenticatable#valid?` call.

Basically, I'd like it to be valid when either of the "parent" strategies are valid? But from this class, I can't access the "parent" strategy methods or mix them in without mixing in too much. How should I approach this?